# In android 4.4.2 Activity resuming loads the default fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, actionbarsherlock, android-4.4-kitkat

In my app i have noticed a strange behaviour in android 4.4.2. I am using a Sherlock Navigation Drawer to show side drawer and replacing fragments to load differnt pages within the same activity.But after minimizing the application and relaunching in android 4.4.2 its loading the default fragmant but in other versions of android its resuming to the fragment from where i left. I have tested with the versions 4.2.2,4.1.2,4.0.2,2.3.3 and its working as i expected and the issue occurs only in android 4.4.2
any help is appriciated....

Answer (score 1):

I think for this reason you are facing problem in 4.4.2 just check the  reason is, that the creator of ActionBarSherlock, Jake Wharton, announced on Google+ that further development of ActionBarSherlock has been stopped. ActionBarSherlock 4.4 is the last release and might get bug fixes – but there won’t be any new features:

```
While there may be a dot release or two in the coming weeks, version 4.4
is shaping up to be The Last Release.
```

For more please check the https://www.grokkingandroid.com/migrating-actionbarsherlock-actionbarcompat/

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why this may happen but you can do some precautions to avoid this. Save the current active fragment position in a `SharedPreference` or inside `onSaveInstanceState` method and inside `onResume()` of your activity check if it is not the currently selected, replace it.